# Gradle GRPC compilation for Java, JS, C#

Tags: javascript, java, gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc

Gradle protobuf plugin easily compiles `.proto` files to java classes.

**Is it possible to do the proto compilation for javascript (or other languages) with the same plugin as well?**

I want to generate ready artefact for several languages, so that other projects don't bother with proto related tasks and just use provided resource... also that will guarantee that every time i make a change to a proto file i get all different language versions compatible with each other...

Answer (score 0):

You can generate for any language that protoc supports. Just add it to the "builtins" (or "plugins" if the support is provided by a protoc plugin, which is always the case if you want to generate GRPC services). For example, to generate C++ files for proto files under all sourceSets:

```
protobuf {
  generateProtoTasks {
    all()*.builtins {
      cpp {}
    }
  }
}
```

Then you will find all generated C++ sources under "build/generated/source/proto/{main|test}/cpp".

Although the Gradle protobuf plugin adds all the generated files to the input of Java compilation, according to my experimentation, Java compilation just ignores non-Java files, so it shouldn't cause you any trouble.

If you do want to generate GRPC services, you may have to compile the GRPC codegen plugins for the other languages except Java, since we only publish the codegen plugin for Java GRPC to the Maven repository.

Comment: Can you give an example project? this does not work for me... Even if it does i need some documentation to customize locations etc... I cannot find anything at all how to compile grpc with gradle to anything else except java...

Comment: Download the [protobuf-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin) source, edit `testProject/build.gradle` and add `all()*.builtins { cpp {} }` under `generateProtoTasks {`. Then run `./gradlew testProject:clean testProject:generateProto`. You will find C++ sources generated under `testProject/build/generated/source/proto/main/cpp/`

Comment: I just realized in my original answer I missed out the `generateProtoTasks` block. Now it's fixed.

Comment: Is there an example for javascript that you could provide? I'm getting this `protoc-gen-js: program not found or is not executable
--js_out: protoc-gen-js: Plugin failed with status code 1.` I've also tried with `javascript {}`

Comment: You need to use a newer protoc, e.g., 3.0.0-beta-2, to have js support.